WalletSendTransactionError: Unexpected error
The error
WalletSendTransactionError: Unexpected error faced while sending the transaction

Code
const transactionSignature = await program.methods
    .createToken(metadata.name, metadata.symbol, metadata.uri)
    .accounts({
        payer: publicKey,
        mintAccount: publicKey,
        metadataAccount: metadataAccount,
        tokenMetadataProgram: TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    })
    .transaction();

const txSig = await sendTransaction(transactionSignature, connection);

can anyone help me to resolve the same?

it is difficult to know what is causing the error. Could you skip preflight and share the tx hash.

const transactionSignature = await program.methods
.createToken(metadata.name, metadata.symbol, metadata.uri)
.accounts({
payer: publicKey,
mintAccount: publicKey,
metadataAccount: metadataAccount,
tokenMetadataProgram: TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
})
.transaction();
  const txSig = await sendTransaction(transactionSignature, connection);


From the code you shared, the issues I can point out to be corrected,

Generate a new keypair for the mint account
sign this transaction with this keypair

const mint = new Keypair();
const tx = await program.methods
    .createToken(metadata.name, metadata.symbol, metadata.uri)
    .accounts({
        payer: publicKey,
        mintAccount: mint.publicKey,
        metadataAccount: metadataAccount,
        tokenMetadataProgram: TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    })
    .signers([mint])
    .transaction();

const txSig = await sendTransaction(tx, connection, {
    skipPreflight: true,
});


Still facing the same error

Could you share the tx hash

Couldn't get that

use the code I provided, log the result of tx variable and share it here.
